# How to solve problem of "scipy pip installation error in python

Tags: python

When I went to install scipy following error has been found in python. Do you know any way how to solve this problem?

```
pip install scipy
```

```
Collecting scipy
  Downloading scipy-1.12.0-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata (60 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 60.4/60.4 kB 14.5 kB/s eta 0:00:00
Requirement already satisfied: numpy<1.29.0,>=1.22.4 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from scipy) (1.26.4)
Downloading scipy-1.12.0-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl (45.8 MB)
   ━━━━━━━━━━━━━╸━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 15.7/45.8 MB 115.5 kB/s eta 0:04:21

ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 438, in _error_catcher
    yield
  File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 561, in read
    data = self._fp_read(amt) if not fp_closed else b""
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 527, in _fp_read
    return self._fp.read(amt) if amt is not None else self._fp.read()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\filewrapper.py", line 98, in read
    data: bytes = self.__fp.read(amt)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\http\client.py", line 479, in read
    s = self.fp.read(amt)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\socket.py", line 707, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\ssl.py", line 1253, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\ssl.py", line 1105, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TimeoutError: The read operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 180, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 245, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 377, in run
    requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\resolver.py", line 179, in resolve
    self.factory.preparer.prepare_linked_requirements_more(reqs)
  File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 552, in prepare_linked_requirements_more
    self._complete_partial_requirements(
  File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 467, in _complete_partial_requirements
    for link, (filepath, _) in batch_download:
  File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\network\download.py", line 183, in __call__
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\progress_bars.py", line 53, in _rich_progress_bar
    for chunk in iterable:
  File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\network\utils.py", line 63, in response_chunks
    for chunk in response.raw.stream(
  File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 622, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 560, in read
    with self._error_catcher():
  File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\contextlib.py", line 158, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(value)
  File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 443, in _error_catcher
    raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, "Read timed out.")
pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out.
```

Comment: you try with increate timeout  with following pip command 

pip install --timeout 300 scipy

Comment: Can you install any packages? Or is it just scipy causing problems? Are you behind a VPN or corporate firewall? This looks like a networking error, so it's something between you and the server that probably isn't scipy's fault

Comment: It seems like there was a timeout error during the installation process, likely due to slow network connection or connectivity issues.

Comment: pip install --timeout 300 scipy  working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways that this could be done, including:

1. You can refresh/reset the libraries in your file explorer where
   your python libraries reside.
2. You can reinstall your IDE and check environment variable path in
   case of Windows OS.